# Exact clearRect on moving clipped image on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a simple side scrolling avoider game in html/javascript using canvas. Having some troubles removing (clearRect) the moving variable height clipped image so it doesn't also remove the sprite/image the user is controlling above, I can get it to remove everything above/below the image but cannot find how to exactly remove the moving shadow image so it doesn't remove the hero of the game as well whilst animating!

https://jsfiddle.net/6k354f5x/3/

Currently the banana is also cleared, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
//<canvas id="board" width="480" height="640"></canvas>

//Getting the canvas
var board = document.getElementById("board");
var cx = board.getContext("2d");

//Example Images
var pipe = new Image();
pipe.src = "http://www.appcycle.me/flappy/img/pipe.png";
var hero = new Image();
hero.src = "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/drunken-peasants-podcast/images/9/9c/Banana-in-8-bit.png/revision/latest?cb=20150821213530";

//Pipe randomness calculated from board height
var pipeVariation = Math.floor((Math.random() * 250) + 1);
var pipeY = 456;
var pipeX = 350; 

//interval
var timer = setInterval(function() { 

  //draw the hero
    cx.drawImage(hero, 0, 150);

    //clear the afterimage
    cx.clearRect(pipeX, 80, pipe.width / 1.6, pipe.height / 1.6);

  //move it on the X-axis some px
    pipeX -= 2;

  //draw the clipped pipe with some Y-axis placement variation from pipeVariation variable
    cx.drawImage(pipe,
                    0, -pipeY+pipeVariation, pipe.width, pipe.height,
                    pipeX, 80, pipe.width / 1.6, pipe.height / 1.6)

  //Temporary to keep pipe from running away while testing
    if (pipeX <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Full canvas animation redraw everything.

When rendering canvas animation that has many elements, such as a game, the most effective method to render is to redraw everything every frame.

At the start of every frame you either clear the whole screen or draw the background image over the top of the last frame (same as clearing) then draw the game elements one by one in order of lowest to highest z-index (where the highest element is on top of all the other elements)

This makes the code very simple as opposed to complex dirty rects schemes that quickly become very complex and can reduce performance.

On all but a small number of devices most rendering is done via the GPU and is very fast (NOTE this does not apply to moveTo, lineTo, shadows, arcs, text, ellipses) Clearing and re-rendering everything can easily be done in 1/60 of a second creating smooth high quality animations

Note on shadows. Do not use the context2D shadows, most browsers and the hardware do not do it well at all and can be a major performance hit. This can be so even if you render one shadow for one small image. It is best to either pre render the shadow, or load a separate shadow as an image.